# Spectral irradiance unit conversion (Jansky)

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, units, unit-conversion

I'm a bit confused between two units for spectral irradiance, specifically $W/sr/m^2/nm$ and $\mu Jy/"^2$, which is analogous to $W/sr/m^2/Hz$.

It seems to me that I need some sort of spectral bandwidth, but I don't get which one to use in the case of hyperspectral data.

Comment: Spectral quantities can be expressed in terms of either frequency or wavelength. Take your pick. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance

Comment: The relationship is $L_\nu\,d\nu=L_\lambda\,d\lambda$.

Comment: Sure, but what number is that? Do I directly use $\nu$ and $\lambda$ or do I need to integrate somehow?

Comment: $d\nu/d\lambda$ or $d\lambda/d\nu$ is not a number. They are functions of $\nu$ or $\lambda$ which follow from $\lambda\nu=c$. So there is not a single conversion factor between the units. The factor depends on the frequency or the wavelength.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm getting it. So the factor $d\nu/d\lambda$ is about equal to $c/\lambda^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, ignoring the minus sign (which is fine).

Comment: Yes since the minus sign simply changes the order of the x-axis. Thank you!

Comment: To see this at work, look at the two spectral radiances here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Correspondence_between_spectral_variable_forms